# (some) Dihedral groups have a right transversal isomorphic to some dihedral group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $D_{2n}=\langle a,b;a^n,b^2,(ba)^2\rangle$ denote the Dihedral Group of order $2n$. Let $H=\langle a^m,b\rangle$ be a subgroup of $D_{2n}$ of *even* index $m$ such that $m$ divides $n$. Choose a right transversal (set of representatives of right cosets of $H$ in $G$) $S=\{b^ia^{2j+i}:i=0,1~\text{and}~0\leq j\leq \frac{m}{2}-1\}$. Clearly $S$ is a right loop (right quasigroup with two sided identity) with respect to the operation defined by $\{x\circ y\}=S\cap Hxy$. ([see more](http://www.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1996.0109)). I wish to show that $S$ is a group; moreover, $S\cong D_{2.\frac{m}{2}}$.

---

Is it sufficient to show that $(a^2)^{\frac{m}{2}}=1, (ba)^2=1$ and $(ba\circ a^2)^2=1$ with respect to the operation $\circ$ ?

Comment: You would need to show that $\circ$ is associative. If you knew that, then it would be enough to verify the defining relations of the dihedral group.

Comment: As I know the definition of Group (A semigroup in which left and right equations have unique solutions), will semigroup with right equations have unique solution imply left equations have solution?? (sorry for rough language). @Derek

Comment: It is not true that in a general semigroup, unique solutions to "right equations" implies unique solutions in "left equations."  Consider the semigroup on  $\{0,1\}$ with multplication given by $0*x=0$ and $1*x=1$.